# How can I call a Proc that takes a block in a different context?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, block

Take this example Proc:

```
proc = Proc.new {|x,y,&block| block.call(x,y,self.instance_method)}
```

It takes two arguments, x and y, and also a block.

I want to execute that block using different values for self. Something like this nearly works:

```
some_object.instance_exec("x arg", "y arg", &proc)
```

However that doesn't allow you to pass in a block. This also doesn't work

```
some_object.instance_exec("x arg", "y arg", another_proc, &proc)
```

nor does

```
some_object.instance_exec("x arg", "y arg", &another_proc, &proc)
```

I'm not sure what else could work here. Is this possible, and if so how do you do it?

Edit: Basically if you can get this rspec file to pass by changing the `change_scope_of_proc` method, you have solved my problem.

```
require 'rspec'

class SomeClass
  def instance_method(x)
    "Hello #{x}"
  end
end

class AnotherClass
  def instance_method(x)
    "Goodbye #{x}"
  end

  def make_proc
    Proc.new do |x, &block|
      instance_method(block.call(x))
    end
  end
end

def change_scope_of_proc(new_self, proc)
  # TODO fix me!!!
  proc
end

describe "change_scope_of_proc" do
  it "should change the instance method that is called" do
    some_class = SomeClass.new
    another_class = AnotherClass.new
    proc = another_class.make_proc
    fixed_proc = change_scope_of_proc(some_class, proc)
    result = fixed_proc.call("Wor") do |x|
      "#{x}ld"
    end

    result.should == "Hello World"
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for supplying test surfacing the issue explicitly

Comment: +1 for the test, thank you, that makes it very easy to see what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this, you need to re-bind the Proc to the new class.

Here's your solution, leveraging some good code from Rails core_ext:

```
require 'rspec'

# Same as original post

class SomeClass
  def instance_method(x)
    "Hello #{x}"
  end
end

# Same as original post

class AnotherClass
  def instance_method(x)
    "Goodbye #{x}"
  end

  def make_proc
    Proc.new do |x, &block|
      instance_method(block.call(x))
    end
  end
end

### SOLUTION ###

# From activesupport lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class.rb

module Kernel
  # Returns the object's singleton class.
  def singleton_class
    class << self
      self
    end
  end unless respond_to?(:singleton_class) # exists in 1.9.2

  # class_eval on an object acts like singleton_class.class_eval.
  def class_eval(*args, &block)
    singleton_class.class_eval(*args, &block)
  end
end

# From activesupport lib/active_support/core_ext/proc.rb 

class Proc #:nodoc:
  def bind(object)
    block, time = self, Time.now
    object.class_eval do
      method_name = "__bind_#{time.to_i}_#{time.usec}"
      define_method(method_name, &block)
      method = instance_method(method_name)
      remove_method(method_name)
      method
    end.bind(object)
  end
end

# Here's the method you requested

def change_scope_of_proc(new_self, proc)
  return proc.bind(new_self)
end

# Same as original post

describe "change_scope_of_proc" do
  it "should change the instance method that is called" do
    some_class = SomeClass.new
    another_class = AnotherClass.new
    proc = another_class.make_proc
    fixed_proc = change_scope_of_proc(some_class, proc)
    result = fixed_proc.call("Wor") do |x|
      "#{x}ld"
    end
    result.should == "Hello World"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thankyou, this is perfect! For the tldrers, from the `activesupport` gem, if you `require 'active_support/core_ext'` you get access to the `Proc#bind` method, which does exactly what I required. Unfortunately, it has been [depreciated in HEAD](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9c857db75788c21f6184279c130e79f21c750f9f) due to a symbol memory leak. It isn't likely there is a better solution though if this is what the rails team ended up using. Also, the code that was used to replaced uses of `Proc#bind` doesn't pass my test - I wonder if they are aware that functionality has been lost...

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can do this, and the trouble isn't passing multiple blocks. Proc's and blocks are closures and capture their bindings at the point of creation. `self` is part of that binding, so even if you change self with `instance_eval`, when you `call` the proc/block it executes in its binding, with the self it closed over:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> class Foo; def mkproc; Proc.new { puts "#{self.class}:#{object_id}" }; end; end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> p = Foo.new.mkproc
=> #<Proc:0x00000001b04338@(irb):1>
irb(main):003:0> p.call
Foo:14164520
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> 'bar'.instance_exec { puts "#{self.class}:#{object_id}"; p.call }
String:16299940
Foo:14164520
```

Ruby will let you capture a closure's [Binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Binding.html) with [Kernel#binding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-binding), but offers no way to set the binding associated with a [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-binding). You can specify a binding for the string version of [Kernel#eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval), but that still doesn't let you change the binding of a proc you call.

```
irb(main):005:0> class BindMe; def get_binding(p=nil); binding; end; end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> b = BindMe.new.get_binding(p)
=> #<Binding:0x00000001f58e48>
irb(main):007:0> eval '"#{self.class}:#{object_id}"', b
=> "BindMe:14098300"
irb(main):008:0> eval '"#{self.class}:#{object_id}"', p.binding
=> "Foo:14164520"
irb(main):009:0> eval "p.call", b
Foo:14164520
```

Comment: You can change the binding of `self` in a proc by passing it directly to `instance_exec`. For example, `'bar'.instance_exec &p` outputs `String:2151790940` when I tried it, showing that self was changed. The key point is procs called inside the proc given to instance_exec don't have their binding changed, which explains the output you were getting. So I don't think this proves one way or the other if what I want to do is possible or not.

Comment: Ah, nice observation.  I think I see a way to use that to get your spec to pass, but have to run off to work now.  I'll fiddle with this later.